# Does the upcoming changes to AppEngine billing mean asynchronous batch operations will be much cheaper than with the current billing model?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In the pursuit of efficient batch operating on AppEngine, I've been experimenting with async calls and have ended up with a request signature that looks like... `/task/batch_remove_model 200 402ms 43582cpu_ms 42859api_cpu_ms`.

I understand that under the current billing model I'd pay for the 43582ms of cpu time, but how would that same resource be billed under the upcoming 'instance based' billing model? At that point am I simply paying per datastore operation?

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will pay for the 402ms of instance time used to server the request, plus you'll pay for each of the datastore operations.  Datastore operations include entity reads and entity and index writes (*not* RPC calls), so the cost will be proportional (probably higher) to what you're paying now.

For more details see the pricing [FAQ](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/a1bfa432e0c002a7).

Comment: Are you sure it wouldn't be significantly cheaper on a per operation basis? For example, with an asynchronous batch delete operation of 512 entities, I get a request signature like `ms=1144 cpu_ms=133141 api_cpu_ms=131251 cpm_usd=3.698185`. The cpu cost of that `api_cpu_ms=131251` is approximately equal too (3.698185*(131251/133141))/1000 correct? That's $0.00364. The same 512 operations charged PER OPERATION amounts to $0.000512 (512*($0.01/10,000)).

Comment: @Steve *index* writes also count as operations.  So you'll also need to account for that, with that much api cpu use, I'd suspect you've got at least 3 or 4 indexes -- so you'll use (512 + (512 * # indexes)) operations (don't forget 2 indexes per property unless you've explicitly disabled indexing). Plus how ever many operations were used to fetch them.

Comment: Good point about the indexes. To start with it just sounded too good to be true that you could get all this free processing done with async calls, but I guess it's more the case that applications that don't take advantage of async operations are going to waste a lot of resources.

Comment: @Steve, Yep, async (done correctly) can reduce app latency via concurrency, which is good for you (and Google).  Hopefully Python will get multithreading soon to give our apps another concurrency boost.  I'm not keen on the datastore cost increase either, but at least the charges will (hopefully) become more transparent.